# Symfony 2 When to use collections and entities?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I feel pretty lost on collections, and entities as it stands.

My purpose:

A user will have one or more abilities. There are a set number of abilities, and numerous users. (A user entity, usertoabilities, abilities)

I want to display a form of the set abilities (lets say running, swimming, climbing), with properties such as (skill level, length of time).

The user would check each ability they have, and select their skill level and time.

My current understanding, is that my form will contain:

a collection of abilities (collection of entities), a collection of skill levels, and a collection times.

The form will print out each row of abilities with the corresponding properties. Where the user selects these abilities and saves them.

Is my understanding correct?

My current approach seems to have me going in circles.

Answer (score 0):

you can create only two Entities (User and ability) and you need to create a ManyToMany Relation where you need to set a field (property) that is the relations field with some annotations where you wil set the "JoinTable" that in this case is "usertoabilities" for the two entities and more fields that will be the "abilities"  you can find more information in http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: With doctrine I'm currently set up so that user and abilities has a 1:M relationship with the "jointable" user_abilities (with property fields), and user_abilities has a M:1 relationship with both user and abilities. I'd be happy to know if this is related, however my question is more concerning the use of form collections and entities.

Comment: oh ok! a collection field type is for "options" and you can use it without an entity and use arrays to pass options and an Entity Field Type is more complete with entities because it have the posibility to do custom queries and much more that is unique of entities. you can find more informacion at http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html